# WordPress Theme (Genesis) Login Button in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress site using the Genesis theme with a login button as follows:

```
    <div class="header_right_section">
        <a href="<?php echo (is_user_logged_in()) ? wp_login_url() : wp_logout_url(get_bloginfo('url')); ?>" class="fadegraybut"><?php echo (is_user_logged_in()) ? 'Log Out' : 'Log In'; ?></a>
        <span id="telnum">PHONE</span>
    </div>
```

Now, I'm not very familiar with PHP and so I'm a bit confused as to what this button is doing, but what I'd like it to do is simply redirect to a different URL (it currently redirects to the admin panel login for some reason).  Can anyone explain the logic flow in this code as it is and if enough information has been provided explain how I can get it to redirect to the right page (e.g. https://example.com)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it seems the code in this example has the intended actions for logged in vs logged out, backwards.

Please try this instead:

```
<div class="header_right_section">
    <a href="<?php echo (is_user_logged_in()) ? wp_logout_url('https://example.com') : wp_login_url() ; ?>" class="fadegraybut"><?php echo (is_user_logged_in()) ? 'Log Out' : 'Log In'; ?></a>
    <span id="telnum">PHONE</span>
</div>
```

### Your original code

This code mixes PHP and HTML, but the logic is controlled by the PHP so we'll focus on the PHP, meaning what is within `<?php` and ends with `?>`.

All PHP lines here begin with `echo` command in order to have an output.

Overall, the [ternary operator `?:`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) is being used here instead of an if-statement for handling if/then logic, and the syntax is

```
(condition) ? what to do if true : what to do if false;
```

This is most clearly seen in the second part:

```
(is_user_logged_in()) ? 'Log Out' : 'Log In';
```

- [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) is a WordPress function that returns true or false according to being logged in or not.
- if user is logged in, it will show `Log Out`. This makes sense, if the user is logged in then you want to present the option to `Log Out`
- if user is not logged in, the other option is presented: `Log In`. This makes sense, since if the user is not yet logged in, then you present the option to `Log In`

In contrast, the first part in the original code seems to have the action logic backwards. It looks like it was made so if you are logged in, it will present you with the login URL. But if you are logged in you don't need to reach a means of logging in, you should already be logged in. Similarly problematic is it also means if logged out, it triggers offers the URL that would log you out. But if you were already logged out, you wouldn't need to perform a log out action. Thus why I feel the code you found must have been coded backwards.

### Solution

Thus, we rearranged the code within the ternary operator structure, to:

```
(is_user_logged_in()) ? wp_login_url() : wp_logout_url('https://example.com'));
```

- `wp_login_url()` is a WordPress function that `returns the URL that allows the user to log in to the site.` see [wp_login_url() documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url) for details
- `wp_logout_url()` is a WordPress function that `returns the URL that allows the user to log out of the site. see [wp_logout_url() documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url) for details
- `wp_logout_url()` allows you to specify a page you want to redirect to after successfully logging out. Since you wanted the example `https://example.com`, we've put that there, just remember to update this to the actual URL you want. It is a string, so we have to enclose in quotes to avoid PHP confusing it with a variable or function, thus: `wp_logout_url('https://example.com')`
- the final `;` properly completes and enables this line of PHP

### Result

So with these changes, when visiting the site, it should now:

- if logged in, show `Log Out`, and clicking it should not only log you out but also redirect you to the URL you specified, 'https://example.com' (just remember to update this to an actual working URL)
- if not logged in, show `Log In`, and clicking it should take you to the login prompt

Comment: Thanks so much, your explanation is very helpful.  So what I'd actually like is for the logic to instead always show 'Log In' and link to a certain URL when the button is clicked.  Is this much different from your proposed solution?  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You're very welcome. In regards to the code, in that case you don't need the benefit of PHP at all, because if you want it to always stay the same, it could just be static HTML, try replacing the entire line `<a href="` with `<a href="https://example.com" class="fadegraybut">Log In</a>`